# Level of uncertainty when measuring a period of time?

Tags: survival, measurement, uncertainty

I need to create a raw data table for my science experiment, but I'm unsure what the level of uncertainty would be when measuring days. How would I determine the level of uncertainty when measuring a period of time?

Comment: I think you can safely say what day it currently is with no uncertainty at all. Can you elaborate on how you are using days in this experiment?

Comment: Im measuring the amount of days it takes beans to germinate or sprout.

Comment: This is a classic survival analysis situation. Do you have any censoring? That is, do you have any beans that still hadn't germinated by the end of the study period?

Comment: yes I had a few beans that didn't germinate by the end of my study period and I didn't include them in my means or standard deviations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly as you do with any other uncertainty, I don't see how measuring days is different from measuring meters.

That is, you can find SEM if you have some statistics of measurements or decide on some measurement uncertainty for each individual one (if you check 'em every day, the uncertainty is probably 0.5 day or so, if you aren't sure if it happened or not within a couple of days, it can be more etc.). Exactly as for any other measurement.